# Where are pm-powersave settings on OpenSUSE 13.2, and are they used?

Tags: opensuse, power-management, laptop, pm-utils, laptop-mode

I am trying to sort out powersaving for OpenSUSE 13.2 running on a laptop.

I found this guide:

https://en.opensuse.org/Powersaving

for understanding Powersaving on OpenSUSE.  However, it appears to not have been changed since 2011, so I feel the information there might be a little out of date.

Now, in that guide they mention pm-utils are being used for powersaving, and that the scripts live in "/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d"  However, on my installation, this directory does not exist.  There is a "/etc/pm/power.d" but this directory contains nothing.  pm-powersave is installed, and I can invoke it with

```
sudo pm-powersave true
```

but without any files in the correct folder (which one should the files go in), does this command actually do anything?

I also noted that the guide referenced using laptop-mode-tools, which is available in the standard repos; however, according to

https://askubuntu.com/questions/312005/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-on-13-04

https://askubuntu.com/questions/172391/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels

for Ubuntu, which uses the pm-powersave scripts, laptop-mode-tools is redundant.  Does this apply to OpenSUSE, and if so, where are the configuration files for pm-powersave?

--------- EDIT -----------
I found

http://newsgroupstats.info/article.jsp?server=nntp.novell.com&group=opensuse.org.help.install-boot-login&postid=157199

which suggests pm-utils is not used.